# Assign one value to multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have table something like this:

```
     id              call_id                         user       call_date       current_id     grp_val
    296030  80ee830b-dcb5-40c2-9568-c0d9082376c6    a@4com.im   08:04:00.000    38124085313:0     1
    296031  80ee830b-dcb5-40c2-9568-c0d9082376c6    b@4com.im   08:04:00.000    38124084629:0     2
    296032  80ee830b-dcb5-40c2-9568-c0d9082376c6    a@5com.im   09:51:00.000    38124255283:0     3
    296033  162ba8a3-3940-4258-8c7d-4ef31c092c8e    a@6com.im   09:51:00.000    38124255283:1     4
    296034  162ba8a3-3940-4258-8c7d-4ef31c092c8g    a@4com.im   13:10:33.753    38124255283:2     5
    296035  162ba8a3-3940-4258-8c7d-4ef31c092c8y    a@4com.im   13:30:41.387    38124255283:4     6
    296042  ed42cb64-70d0-44f9-8ac6-2cac4b4c19c5    a@4com.im   16:28:00.000    38124894109:0     1
    296043  ed42cb64-70d0-44f9-8ac6-2cac4b4c19c5    b@4com.im   16:28:00.000    38124892991:0     2
    296044  6370e3ac-fbda-4e0f-b946-71d4f87fccae    a@4com.im   16:41:00.000    38124910303:0     1
    296045  82e7db68-5c99-499a-9f9b-4d799f4df2e4    a@4com.im   16:41:00.000    38124910303:1     2
```

What I want to achieve is group all similar calls together with one id. Something like this:

```
id              call_id                             user         call_date   current_id     grp_val  exch_id
    296030  80ee830b-dcb5-40c2-9568-c0d9082376c6    a@4com.im   08:04:00.000 38124085313:0     1      1
    296031  80ee830b-dcb5-40c2-9568-c0d9082376c6    b@4com.im   08:04:00.000 38124084629:0     2      1
    296032  80ee830b-dcb5-40c2-9568-c0d9082376c6    a@5com.im   09:51:00.000 38124255283:0     3      1
    296033  162ba8a3-3940-4258-8c7d-4ef31c092c8e    a@6com.im   09:51:00.000 38124255283:1     4      1
    296034  162ba8a3-3940-4258-8c7d-4ef31c092c8g    a@4com.im   13:10:33.753 38124255283:2     5      1
    296035  162ba8a3-3940-4258-8c7d-4ef31c092c8y    a@4com.im   13:30:41.387 38124255283:4     6      1  
    296042  ed42cb64-70d0-44f9-8ac6-2cac4b4c19c5    a@4com.im   16:28:00.000 38124894109:0     1      2
    296043  ed42cb64-70d0-44f9-8ac6-2cac4b4c19c5    b@4com.im   16:28:00.000 38124892991:0     2      2
    296044  6370e3ac-fbda-4e0f-b946-71d4f87fccae    a@4com.im   16:41:00.000 38124910303:0     1      3
    296045  82e7db68-5c99-499a-9f9b-4d799f4df2e4    a@4com.im   16:41:00.000 38124910303:1     2      3
```

How can I achieve the above result from the mentioned table?

Comment: How do you define similar calls?

Comment: You seem to define "similar" as "has a group value that is either 1 or is one greater than the previous row when sorted by id" ?

Comment: @CleanBold Similar calls are when either the call_id is same or the value before ":" is same in current_id column, when compared with the previous id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN grp_val = 1 THEN 1 END) OVER(ORDER BY id)
```

This effectively turns the grp_val into a column of 1 (when grp_val is 1) or null (otherwise), and when ordered by ID, it is implied that for every row the SUM() OVER() will operate over all the previous rows including the current row. It is the short form of `SUM(CASE WHEN grp_val = 1 THEN 1 END) OVER(ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)`

If your data was thus:

```
grp_val, CASE WHEN ..., SUM OVER
1        1              1 (1)
2        NULL           1 (1+NULL)
3        NULL           1 (1+NULL+NULL)
1        1              2 (1+NULL+NULL+1)
2        NULL           2 (1+NULL+NULL+1+NULL)
```

You can also use LAG to look at the previous row values, like `LAG(call_id) OVER(ORDER BY id)` it's the previous row call id, so you can say `CASE WHEN LAG(call_id) OVER(ORDER BY id) = call_id OR LAG(LEFT(current_id, CHARINDEX(':', current_id))) OVER(ORDER BY id) = LEFT(current_id, CHARINDEX(':', current_id)) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END` - it's the "if prev row call_id is same as this row, or prev row current_id before colon is same as this row current_id before colon, then 0 else 1" .. and these 0/1 gould be SUM OVER'd in a similar way, but it's a bit more wordy

Comment: I didn't understand the process completely but it works perfectly. Thanks!!

Comment: The OVER cause provides us a way to break a set of results into ranges. When we call `SUM(something) OVER(ORDER BY)` .. it establishes a running total; for every row all the previous row's `something` are summed up to create a running total. NULL works like 0 in a SUM

Comment: @CaisJard What if there was no order? In that case is there any option other than a self join?

Comment: If there's no order then your rules kinda fall apart...